# mysql database replication

Tags: mysql

I want to create Database replication i try but some problem is there so give me full steps of How To Set Up Database Replication In MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Never done it personally at work but we do use it.
Seems that you want to setup a master/slave setup, the slave beeing the replicated server.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html (check the documentation is up to date with your mysql version.)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a step by step instruction how to get MySQL master-slave replication automatically installed and later scaled http://blog.jelastic.com/2017/03/14/scalable-mysql-master-slave-replication/ (if you are ready to run this cluster in the specific cloud)

Comment: The answer should be accessible here, not requiring a second click to an outside resource. It's a good reference though.